# Android ScrollView takes all the screen

Tags: android, user-interface

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textt" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            style="@style/textstyle" />  
    </LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
    style="@style/nextButton"
    android:background="@drawable/next_button"   
    android:text="@string/xxx"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="ethod" />
```

When the textview is very long, scroll takes all the screen and there's no button and other stuff showing which should be in the bottom.

Comment: post the complete layout code with the buttons and everything

Comment: What do you want to achieve. You want to display a huge text with a button below it. From what I understand You need a textview which will display large text like About or terms and conditions page and a button below.But the button should not scroll, only text should scroll. Is this your requirement? If yes then let me know. we can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="afgfffffffjbhhjkhholhjbhlkjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="ethod"
        android:text="button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but you can try this approach:

Your XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:editable="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="This is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng textThis is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng textThis is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng textThis is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng textThis is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng textThis is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng textThis is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng textThis is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng text.This is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng text.This is very very very loooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnng text." >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_chkin"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Accept" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed.setSelection(0);
    ed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getWindow()
                    .setSoftInputMode(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        }
    });
}
```

This is not a perfect solution but something near.

Answer (score 0):

Have ScrollView and ButtonView in a RelativeLayout, with LayoutParams as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nextbutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textt" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            style="@style/textstyle" />  
    </LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
    style="@style/nextButton"
    android:background="@drawable/next_button"   
    android:text="@string/xxx"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="ethod" /> 

</RelativeLayout?
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        <ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
android:background="@drawable/background">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textt" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@style/textstyle" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
style="@style/nextButton"
android:background="@drawable/next_button"   
android:text="@string/xxx"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:onClick="ethod"
```

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip" />

Check this now it will show button at bottom even if you scroll complete.

Answer (score -1):

If you use LinearLayout - use weight as Kumar said.
My choise in your problem is to use RelativeLayout and "above" property for ScrollView (if you want static button below scrollView).

If you want Button under TextView in ScrollView - bring button element into ScrollView.